# How to play audio on the Lottie animation json file in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, lottie

I'm currently trying to play a JSON animation exported from After Effects with now supports audio files.

I used the local JSON file I created and an animation plays perfectly (i am talking about the animation f, so it proves that the file is working) but it does not play the audio.

This my JSON file

```
{
  "v": "5.7.6",
  "fr": 30,
  "ip": 0,
  "op": 390,
  "w": 1080,
  "h": 1920,
  "nm": "Comp 1",
  "ddd": 0,
  "assets": [
    {
      "id": "image_0",
      "w": 597,
      "h": 676,
      "u": "images/",
      "p": "img_0.png",
      "e": 0
    },{
      "id": "audio_0",
      "u": "images/",
      "p": "aud_0.mp3",
      "e": 0
    }
  ],
  "layers": [
    {
      "ddd": 0,
      "ind": 1,
      "ty": 2,
      "nm": "magic-box.png",
      "cl": "png",
      "refId": "image_0",
      "sr": 1,
      "ks": {
        "o": {
          "a": 0,
          "k": 100,
          "ix": 11
        },
        "r": {
          "a": 0,
          "k": 0,
          "ix": 10
        },
        "p": {
          "a": 0,
          "k": [
            -184,
            2060,
            0
          ],
          "ix": 2,
          "l": 2
        },
        "a": {
          "a": 0,
          "k": [
            6.5,
            670,
            0
          ],
          "ix": 1,
          "l": 2
        },
        "s": {
          "a": 1,
          "k": [
            {
              "i": {
                "x": [
                  0.833,
                  0.833,
                  0.833
                ],
                "y": [
                  0.833,
                  0.833,
                  0.833
                ]
              },
              "o": {
                "x": [
                  0.167,
                  0.167,
                  0.167
                ],
                "y": [
                  0.167,
                  0.167,
                  0.167
                ]
              },
              "t": 20,
              "s": [
                36,
                36,
                100
              ]
            },
            {
              "i": {
                "x": [
                  0.833,
                  0.833,
                  0.833
                ],
                "y": [
                  0.833,
                  0.833,
                  0.833
                ]
              },
              "o": {
                "x": [
                  0.167,
                  0.167,
                  0.167
                ],
                "y": [
                  0.167,
                  0.167,
                  0.167
                ]
              },
              "t": 30,
              "s": [
                115,
                115,
                100
              ]
            },
            {
              "t": 35,
              "s": [
                100,
                100,
                100
              ]
            }
          ],
          "ix": 6,
          "l": 2
        }
      },
      "ao": 0,
      "ip": 0,
      "op": 399,
      "st": 0,
      "bm": 0
    },{
      "ddd": 0,
      "ind": 19,
      "ty": 6,
      "nm": "James holden - Lump [pleer.com].mp3",
      "cl": "mp3",
      "refId": "audio_0",
      "sr": 1,
      "au": {
        "lv": {
          "a": 0,
          "k": [
            0,
            0
          ],
          "ix": 1
        }
      },
      "ip": 0,
      "op": 391.05306122449,
      "st": 0,
      "bm": 0
    }
  ],
"markers": []
]
}
```

Comment: What is the guy named 'the animation f'?  An animation file?

Comment: Where did you see support for Audio? I've seen this one https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-web/wiki/Audio but it's for web and says it's not on Lottie itself.

Comment: @Larme this my JSON file on how to play audio?

Comment: Question: Does Lottie supports playing sound at the same time of the animation? If not, it means that it's up to you to play it. You can parse the JSON, but you'll also need to read the parameters: what means "ddd" value, "ind", etc. Like is it only a part of the sound playing, offset? Effects, etc, and what if the animation loop, etc.